# "It starts at..." vs. "It is at..."?

Tags: present-tense, future

What is the difference between "It **starts** at 9pm" and "It **is** at 9pm" when we speak about future event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, but not always, the second phrase denotes shorter events, "the race is at 9pm" while the first is used for longer ones "the party starts at 9pm". Otherwise the difference is purely idiomatic.